# How to make items fade in on scroll in sequence?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Currently I have 4 divs in a row that I have been able to fade in on scroll using javascript and setting the css opacity to 0 before the transition, seen here:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(window).scroll(function () {
    $('.fadein').each(function (i) {

        var bottom_of_element = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
        var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

        if (bottom_of_window > bottom_of_element) {
            $(this).animate({ 'opacity': '1' }, 1000);
        }

    });
});
```

I want to make it so that the same divs fade in on scroll, one right after the other. I've seen a lot of examples of this but they all seem to only work when the page loads. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

When i was looking for a similar requirement like yours few months ago, i found the below solution with AOS

just need to link below CSS and Javascript and you are ready to go.
saved me lots of time and hope it will help you too.

CSS

```
<link href="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

JS

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.js"></script>
```

Initialize AOS

```
<script> AOS.init(); </script>
```

Then wrap any div you need to animate

```
<div data-aos="fade-up"></div>
```

Support site
[https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/]

Comment: This would still fade in multiple divs in order?

Comment: just wrap the target <div> with tag <data-aos="your animation">. May need to do few adjustments to get it working the way you want but it will be a success at the end.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of JS libraries to do that, I recommend using `laxx.js` OR you can use pure js to the parallax effect [parallex effect using vanilla js](https://medium.com/@ilonacodes/front-end-shorts-how-to-create-parallax-effect-with-vanilla-js-b9f3c92544ed)